# What redis version to use on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

AWS ElastiCache [Documentations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/SelectEngine.Uses.html) provides a good comparison between different Redis versions (3.2.6 and 3.2.10) but I am not sure which one to use. Redis 3.2.6 has in-transit and at-rest encryption with no resizing capability, while Redis 3.2.10 has the online cluster resizing capabilities but does not provide any kind of encryption. Which one should I prefer for hosting a site with a small number (100s) of users per day?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a hard compliance requirement, such as PCI DSS or HIPAA, that requires data protection, then you may have no choice but to use 3.2.6. Note that you can still do [offline resizing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/scaling-redis-cluster-mode-enabled.html#redis-cluster-resharding-offline) with this version.

Otherwise, 3.2.10 is a better choice because of the online resizing capabilities which gives true elasticity that let you scale to millions of users per day.

Good luck!